# Cannot access log4net.GlobalContext - Why not?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, ado.net, log4net

I have an AdoNetAppender logging to a SQL Server database.  It works fine; however, I want to add some custom parameters.  I have seen an approach like the following:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["MyColumn"] = "MyValue";
```

However, when I try to do the same, I get this message:

```
Cannot access internal class 'GlobalContext' here.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks right. The problem is with where that line is located rather than the line itself. Without more information I can't tell you anything else.

Comment: Do you know where it should be?  Is it a certain namespace?

Comment: I don't know exactly where it needs to be. I haven't run into any problems with it placed after the `ILog` declaration and before and `XMLConfigurator` calls.